# Does Battlefield Forge add two mana to your pool each time it is tapped?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Do cards like [Battlefield Forge](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Battlefield%20Forge) add 2 mana each time it's tapped or is it just one of the two tapped mana options? Or can you choose between both at once vs one? And is the mana only there while it's tapped?

{T}: Add {1} to your mana pool.

{T}: Add {R} or {W} to your mana pool. Battlefield Forge deals 1 damage to you.

Comment: I believe your second question is answered by the other question you asked; mana is there until it is spent or until the end of the step/phase. The tapped status of the land has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Whoops, hadn't looked at the other question - agreed, the two questions here are already answered.

Comment: "is the mana only there while it's tapped?" From this question, I suspect you have a misunderstanding between the relationship between land and mana. A lot of new players think that a card that says "Add {R} to your mana pool" means "search your library for a Mountain card and put it on the battlefield" or "pretend you have a Mountain card in play which hangs around permanently" or something similar. But neither of these is how the card actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll only get one mana, and like all mana, it'll be there until you spend it or until the end of the current step/phase. (There are a very small number of cards like [Omnath, Locus of Mana](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Omnath%2C%20Locus%20of%20Mana) in the game which change this, but they clearly, explicitly say so.)

Abilities are of the form "cost: effect". You pay the cost, and get the effect. In this case the cost is simply tapping the land. So you can choose one of those abilities to activate, then you'll have tapped the land, and you won't be able to activate the other anymore.